# Unwanted space horizontal and vertical scroll space in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, responsive-design

I am working on CSS effects,
In the code, I append divs for showing balls to document body with random size and color. But there is extra scroll space being generated with the code.
I am struck with the extra scroll that is being generated both horizontally and vertically with the balls.

The HTML page will not contain more than two lines.

So far my code for the HTML page I created [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/devrushi41/pen/yLOXrwZ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cae1531884.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <style>
        body {

            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }

        .ball {
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 100%;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        .headings {
            font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
            height: 100vh;
            padding-left: 2rem;
            position: relative;
        }

        .vertical-center {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        .social-links {
            padding: 5px;
            color: #121212;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="vertical-center">
            <div class="header headings">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
         
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>

        const colors = ["#3CC157", "#2AA7FF", "#d3d3d3", "#FCBC0F", "#F85F36"];

        const numBalls = 50;
        const balls = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
            let ball = document.createElement("div");
            ball.classList.add("ball");
            ball.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
            ball.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vw`;
            ball.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}vh`;
            ball.style.transform = `scale(${Math.random()})`;
            ball.style.width = `${Math.random()}em`;
            ball.style.height = ball.style.width;

            balls.push(ball);
            document.body.append(ball);

        }

        // Keyframes
        balls.forEach((el, i, ra) => {
            let to = {
                x: Math.random() * (i % 2 === 0 ? -11 : 11),
                y: Math.random() * 12
            };

            let anim = el.animate(
                [
                    { transform: "translate(0, 0)" },
                    { transform: `translate(${to.x}rem, ${to.y}rem)` }
                ],
                {
                    duration: (Math.random() + 1) * 2000, // random duration
                    direction: "alternate",
                    fill: "both",
                    iterations: Infinity,
                    easing: "ease-in-out"
                }
            );
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `But there is extra scroll space being generated with the code.` ... The container controls the scroll behvaior. Try `overflow-x: auto`

Comment: That worked for full screen view but is not working in mobile view

Comment: In a mobile view, the user will be able to touch-drag right for hidden content

Comment: There is no need for that touch drag The page does not contain more than 2 lines of html content

Comment: With the container not being the problem, some other aspect of your code is resulting in the undesirable results. Possibly you have a closing tag extra or an opening tag not closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the body `width` to `100vw` ( viewport width ) and `height` to `100vh` ( viewport height ), and also hide the scrollbar by setting body's `overflow` to `hidden`.

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will make horizontal content inaccessible.

Comment: That worked for full-screen view but is not working in mobile view I am still getting scroll for mobile view

Comment: For me it works both on mobile and full-screen. Did you remove any of the height or width? If so I can try something else. If not, I really have no idea